# How do I calculate what the TOTAL Wallet fees are going to be with Bitcoin-Qt v0.6.3?

Tags: wallet

The new release of BitcoinQt Wallet v0.6.3 looks much better but I still can't find out how much the total fees are to send coins. 
My wallet has 0.52390169 BTC and I tried to spend it and got the message "Total exceeds your balance when the .01  BTC tranasaction fee is included" Fair enough so I reduced the spend to 0.51390169 and the get the message "Total exceeds your balance when the .23 BTC tranasaction fee is included"
This doesn't seem right or fair.
How do I calculate what the TOTAL fees are going to be?

Comment: Welcome to bitcoin.stackexchange! This is a good question, but I'm pretty sure that there's no simple answer unfortunately, since it depends on the history of the coins in your wallet. You might be interested in this: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3400/516

Answer (score 2):

The fee will change with time, if it happened to be high due to the coins being recently received.

There is a fork of the client that doesn't require any fee to be paid.  Your transaction will just take a day or so to get any confirmations.

You can wait to let the coins in your wallet age and then at least the fee should be small and consistent.